# Why the main theme isn't applied in the preview?

Tags: theming, entities

When I’m in administration mode, using the 'seven' theme, and I click on **Preview**, instead of using the main theme, the preview uses seven's stylesheets, which is silly-willy because it’s not what I would expect from a preview.

Comment: Because that's the way it was designed and written by Drupal developers?

Comment: @gurghet i think you post this question in drupal meta for discussion http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thankyou mouot! I’d like to mark your question but I can’t figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of reasons why the main theme isn't applied. I think this comment by merlinofchaos sums up some of the larger hurdles well:

> Right now, in Drupal, we store temporary data in a cache by caching the generated form. In order to preview, we have to process that form and reassemble data. This is fine when you click preview, but in a system like this, you're actually visiting a different URL from the form.
>
> Logically, we could put the form build id in the URL and load the form and process it, but there are several weaknesses with that:
>
> 1. It is wasteful (processing a form that was not submitted)
> 2. Form build IDs are sha generated strings. There is no way to reproduce it if you don't have it. This means you can't do content locking.
> 3. It continues the trend on Drupal of the form owning the data when the form typically should only be a representation of the data.

[Read More »](https://www.drupal.org/node/1510544#comment-5810258)

Lot's of contrib modules have attempted to address these issues:

- [Site Preview System](https://www.drupal.org/project/sps)
- [Page Preview](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagepreview)

That said, "[Allow to preview content in an actual live environment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1510544)" recently [made it into Drupal 8 Core](https://www.drupal.org/commitlog/commit/2/d72c0f98ec41bd2dfe43e5bf7c0e0821cd8bee6f)

But don't get too excited. "[Allow content creators to preview exactly how content will appear on the site after it's saved](https://www.drupal.org/node/2334199)" is still very much a work in progress. And recent comments indicate it will be a Drupal 9, not 8 issue.